# How to update the huge table column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with **9918751** records in it, please find below is data structure,

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| start_ip           | varchar(32)  | YES  | UNI | NULL              |                |
| end_ip             | varchar(32)  | YES  | UNI | NULL              |                |
| country            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| region             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| city               | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| country_conf       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| region_conf        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| city_conf          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| country_code       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| region_code        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| city_code          | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| two_letter_country | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| creation_datetime  | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

In my table the `start_ip` and `end_ip` column contains valid IPv4 IP Address(like `192.168.1.1`, `12.23.34.22` etc), Now I want to update all rows(9918751) to convert the IP address to integer using `INET_ATON()` function. When I am running below query

```
update geo_location_info set start_ip = INET_ATON(start_ip);
```

This query was taking too much time as to update the 9918751 rows and it was not completing the update. Please let me know any alternative (store procedure ?)

Comment: Bound your query. ie, run it 10 times, once for id = 1*, 2*, 3*, etc

Comment: you can create a cursor which will update only one row per iteration. will take a lot of time but wont return errors

Comment: Which is fast and efficient solution ? stored procedure ? cursor or bound query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to use a loop for the update.  The problem is that the function call takes a while and queries can time out.  In addition, updating almost 10 million rows puts a certain burden on the logging mechanisms for maintaining data integrity.  Assuming the `id` is the populated incrementally, you might do this in groups of 10,000 or maybe 100,000.  Unfortunately, you can't really use @Stewarts idea, but almost half of all the rows are likely to start with `1`.

The basic loop is:

```
set @len := 10000, @i := 1;

while @i * @len < 10000000 do
     update geo_location_info
        set start_ip = INET_ATON(start_ip)
        where id between @len*@i and @len*(@i + 1) - 1;
     set @i := @i + 1;
end while;
```

Unfortunately, in MySQL, you need to put this into a stored procedure -- because control flow mechanisms (such as `while`) are only allowed in stored programs.  So, something more like:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure do_update ()
begin
    set @len := 10000, @i := 1;
    select @max := max(id) from geo_location_info;

    while @i * @len <= @max do
         update geo_location_info
            set start_ip = INET_ATON(start_ip)
            where id between @len*@i and @len*(@i + 1) - 1;
         set @i := @i + 1;
    end while;
end $$
delimiter ;
```